# Change the list of import suggestions in Eclipse (PyDev)

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, eclipse-jdt

I often bind a module to a local name using [import as](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/), e.g. `import numpy as np`.

When I use `np.`, how can I configure Eclipse so that `import numpy as np` shows up in the list of import suggestions (when hitting  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>1</kbd> )?

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.